# JPA Criteria API: how to express literal true and literal false?

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

How can I express literal `true` and literal `false` in JPA's Criteria API?

I'm looking for something like `Predicate alwaysTrue = CriterialBuilder.DefaultLiterals.TRUE` (analogous to `java.lang.Boolean.TRUE`).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

To get an always **true** `Predicate` instance, use [`criteriaBuilder.and()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#and(javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...)).
To get an always **false** `Predicate` instance, use [`criteriaBuilder.or()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#or(javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...)).

Comment: `javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate always = true;` results in `Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to Predicate`.

Comment: `CriteriaBuilder.and()` returns an always true predicate. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#and%28javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...%29

Comment: ... and for a `Predicate` instance that always evaluates to `false`, one can use `javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate alwaysFalse = aCriteriaBuilder.and().not()` ... what where the API designers thinking?!

Comment: You can use `CriteriaBuilder.or()`. I also find this API awful.

Comment: @JBNizet Are those `and()` and `or()` equivalent to `conjunction()` and `disjunction()`, respectively? Thanks.

Answer (score 32):

[CriteriaBuilder#conjunction()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#conjunction()) returns a TRUE predicate.

[CriteriaBuilder#disjunction()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#disjunction()) returns a FALSE predicate.

```
/**
 * Create a conjunction (with zero conjuncts).
 * A conjunction with zero conjuncts is true.
 *
 * @return and predicate
 */
Predicate conjunction();

/**
 * Create a disjunction (with zero disjuncts).
 * A disjunction with zero disjuncts is false.
 *
 * @return or predicate
 */
Predicate disjunction();
```

Comment: Are those methods equivalent to `and()` and `or()`, respectively? And actually are the right way to do? Thanks.

Comment: No, `conjunction()` and `disjunction()` do not take arguments like `and()` and `or()` do.  `conjunction()` returns only a true predicate whereas `and()` can return either a true or false predicate, depending on its arguments.  Similarly, `disjunction()` returns only a false whereas `or()` can return a true or false, depending on its arguments.

Answer (score 16):

Although the other answers solve the problem, I think they don't show the intention of the code, which should be "an always true predicate".

Personally I think the approach below is more clear, although a bit longer.

**Always true**

```
criteriaBuilder.isTrue(criteriaBuilder.literal(true));
```

**Always false**

```
criteriaBuilder.isFalse(criteriaBuilder.literal(true));
```

Comment: Much nicer to have code that you understand what it's doing just by looking at it!